# Replacing legend item names in Carto VL

Tags: carto, carto-vl

I am trying to replace legend item names in a Carto VL map. Using an example from the [documentation](https://carto.com/developers/carto-vl/v0.10.0/guides/add-legends/) which describes how to rename the "CARTO_VL_OTHERS" category, I was able to rename one of my legend items. For example:

```
colorLegendList +=
            `<li><span class="point-mark" style="background-color:${color};border: 1px solid black;"></span> 
                <span>${legend.key.replace("EN", "Endangered")}</span></li>\n`;
```

Which results in:

[image]

How would I rename the rest of the legend items as:

- VU - Vulnerable
- CR - Critically Endangered
- LT - Least Threatened

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create an Object before `layer.on('loaded'...` with the legend keys you want to use for this dataset, for example:

```js
    const LEGEND_KEYS = {
      LT: 'Least Threatened',
      VU: 'Vulnerable',
      CR: 'Critically Endangered',
      EN: 'Endangered'
    }
```

And then, when updating the legend:

```js
colorLegendList +=
            `<li><span class="point-mark" style="background-color:${color};border: 1px solid black;"></span> 
                <span>${LEGEND_KEYS[legend.key]}</span></li>\n`;
```

Comment: Thanks Elena, this worked perfectly. I have been wondering about this for a while so I am glad I finally asked.